# What's the difference between 省略 and 略称？

Tags: words

I've come across these words many times over the years, but I realized that I don't have a proper conceptualization of the concrete difference between them. Can I ask for some sample sentences which highlight the nuances in these words?

Answer (score 3):

What confuses you is, perhaps, English. Let's try a dictionary:

> [**Abbreviation**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abbreviation)
>
> **1** : a shortened form of a written word or phrase used in place of the whole word or phrase
> **2** : the act or result of abbreviating something : abridgment

The Japanese word that corresponds to definition **1** is **略語**. Among that, shortened forms of names (usually proper nouns) are especially called **略称**. What **省略** rightly corresponds to is definition **2** of *abbreviation*.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So 略称 is a shortening of one word or phrase. And 省略 is a shortening of a longer passage of text. Is that accurate?

Comment: @kandyman No it's more like "shortening" and "the shortened", one stands for the action and the other, product.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment about "shortening" and "the shortened".

Comment: @kandyman Sorry for my poor & confusing English usage... What I meant was that, if I understand correctly, Definition 1 stands for a **word**, that's a shortened form of another word or phrase, while Definition 2 stands for an **act**, that makes a long expression into a shorter one. And 略称 could only be the counterpart of Def 1, while 省略 only Def 2.

Answer (score 0):

I can teach you what the difference between 略称 and 省略.
略称 means that you can make a short-cut ONLY for one name/group. So, for example, UN in Japanese is 国際連合, but you can do 略称 as 国連.
On the other hand, 省略 is used when you skip/omit something, for example, you can say that 長さの単位を省略する。, which means that you omit the unit of length.

Comment: Wait, doesn't 省略 also mean a shortening (abbreviation)?

Comment: 省略 includes the meaning(abbreviation) as well.  So, just 略称 is a specific word to express only an abbreviation.  You can't use 略称 in this way, 長さの単位を略称する.

Comment: So can I say - 「国連」は「国際連合」の省略です - ?　Is that natural too?

Comment: Yeah, you can say in that way!